# Employer search statistics for last 50-100

Tags: feature-request, jobs, statistics

For me the total search statistics are not that useful.

Would showing the stats for the last 50 or 100 searches show a better picture of what employers are currently looking and what countries?

Comment: I think this is very useful! I'm constantly looking at careers just to understand what employers are **looking for**